ISP blocked discord so I added discord domains to host file but something missing
in my country discord is blocked, some isp users can easily access it by just changing their DNS however my isp does not allow it. That is why I tried to add some domains and IP addresses of discord to the host file in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc".
I added lines below.
162.159.128.233 www.discord.com

162.159.128.233 status.discord.com

162.159.128.233 discord.com

162.159.128.233 updates.discord.com

162.159.135.234 discord.gg

162.159.135.234 gateway.discord.gg

162.159.129.233 cdn.discordapp.com

162.159.129.233 discordapp.com

162.159.128.235 latency.discord.media

162.159.128.235 discord.media

104.17.117.93 discord.co

104.18.37.76 dis.gd

I can successfully log into Discord from the browser and send ping to those addresses on cmd but my Discord Win 11 app does not work. It stays at updating discord ( retrying always).
Am I missing some domains for the discord desktop app?

The Discord desktop application uses many more domains than what you've added. You've got some, but not nearly enough to have the app work.

I believe so too. Is there a way for me to learn all the domains discord desktop app uses?

Use a tools such as Glasswire, Sniffnet or Portmaster to sniff all traffic from an application.
Start the network monitoring tool, start the Discord app, and find all the IP addresses it tries to contact.
N.B.

Your ISP might report on activity to your locale's law enforcement organizations.
Check any application at VirusTotal before using.


thanks I will try it!
